# ADAM activity

Tags: android-activity, adam

We have an application that will retrive intformation from ADAM server.

I would like to moniter the user activity on ADAM server and would like to capture the user requests on the ADAM server.

Is there any tool that will help to get this info.

-svr

Comment: ADAM = ? Active Directory/Application Mode?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools that come out of the box:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776460.aspx

Ldp is a GUI tool that works well for your intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: http://www.quest.com/intrust-for-active-directory/ it works for ADAM as well

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [LogParser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659) to query user activity in ADAM. You can redirect the output to a file or sql table. [Here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3515886/Import-Security-event-logs-using-Log-parser-and-SQL-Server.htm) is an article on how to automate LogParser for extracting data from the windows security event log.

If you're a c# programmer you could write a small app using the EventLogWatcher class to filter security events and insert them in a sql table.